# To prove $P^2 = P$ meaning $P^n = P$ and $(I-P)^n = I-P$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So the question is that when a square matrix $P$ fulfills the equality that $P^2 = P$

Prove that $P^n = P$ and $(I-P)^n = I -P$

So for first $P^n = P$

I tried to prove by

$P^n = P^{n-2}P^2$

So given $P^2 = P$

$P^n = P^{n-2}P^2 = P^{n-2}P = P^{n-1}$

By same way it we can deduce

$P^{n-1} = P^{n-2} = P^{n-3} = ... = P^2 = P$

or my second attempt is that as $P^2 = P$

$P^{-1}PP = P^{-1}P$

$P = I$

Hence that

$P^n = I^n = I = P$

Which do you think is more suitable as proving???

And for second question now that we know $P = I$

For $(I-P)^n$,

I thought that $I - P = 0$, a zero matrix

and hence that $0^n = 0$

Is my proving, incomplete or not logical?? Please give feedback

Comment: In general, $P$ is a singular matrix, which means that its inverse $P^{-1}$ does not exist. Use a) to prove b)

Comment: Can you say how you got $I-P=0$?

Comment: For the second eqaulity, note that $(I-P)^2=I^2-2P+P^2=I-P$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Because that I got $P = I$ from the first proving

Comment: Do you really think $P=I$ is correct? Note that the zer0 matrix also satisfies the hypothesis.

Comment: @Jochen Then is it better to prove it this way that by using mathematical induction. Let $P^k = P$ be true. Then $P^{k+1} = PP^k = P^2$, which we are give $P^2=P$, $P^{k+1} = P$ So hence prove $P^k = P$

Comment: hints : For the first one, use induction on $n$. For the second one, use the binomial theorem on $(I-P)^n$.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. You're right, if $P$ is regular, then $P=I$.

Comment: Or for the second one, you can use induction as well.

Comment: @Jochen Such that let $(I-P)^{n} =(I-P)$ be true, then $(I-P)^{n+1} = (I-P)^n(I-P) = (I-P)^2 = I^2 -2P +P^2$, here we know $P^2 = P$ So we can deduce $I - P$. Hence $(I-P)^n = I-P$. You are saying this??

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to say :)

Comment: See my comment on Sundar's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $P^2 = P$.

To prove that
$$
P^n = P, \ \ \ (n \in \mathbf{N})
$$
we can use the principle of induction.

Clearly, $P^n = P$ for $n = 1$.

Assume that $P^m = P$ for some positive integer $m$.

Then
$$
P^{m + 1} = P^m P = P P = P^2 = P
$$

This completes the induction.

Hence,
$$
P^n = P, \ \ \mbox{for all} \ \ n \in \mathbf{N}
$$

Next, when $n = 1$,
$$
(I - P)^n = (I - P)^1 = I - P
$$

Assume that
$$
(I - P)^m = I - P
$$
for some positive integer $m$.

Then we find that
$$
(I - P)^{m + 1} = (I - P)^m (I - P) = (I - P) (I - P) = I - 2 P + P^2
$$

Since $P^2 = P$, we get
$$
(I - P)^{m + 1} = I - 2 P + P = I - P
$$

This completes the induction.

Hence, we conclude that
$$
(I - P)^n = (I - P) \ \ \mbox{for all} \ \ n \in \mathbf{N}
$$

Comment: There's no need to repeat the *same* inductive proof for the second case. Instead.  simply verify that $\,(I-P)^2 = I-P,\,$ so the claim follows from the first proof, by replacing $\,P\,$ by $\,I-P.\ \ $